# Python: Why is the thread target being read as a variable?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import os
import threading
import time

def downloadSize():
    while True:
        statinfo = os.path.getsize('minecraft_server.1.8.jar')
        statinfo = statinfo/8
        print(statinfo + "K")
        time.sleep(1)

def downloadFile():
    with urllib.request.urlopen('https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.8/minecraft_server.1.8.jar') as response, open('minecraft_server.1.8.jar', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

def Main():
    downloadSize = threading.Thread(target=downloadSize, args=())
    downloadFile = threading.Thread(target=downloadFile, args=())
    downloadFile.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    downloadSize.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

When ever I run this code, I keep getting an error when I try to start the downloadSize thread, I just can't figure it out? I am using Python 3.4.2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my_username\Desktop\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:\Users\my_username\Desktop\test.py", line 19, in Main
    downloadSize = threading.Thread(target=downloadSize, args=())
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'downloadSize' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same name for a local variable and a global function. Change one of these to resolve the issue.

```
downloadSize = threading.Thread(target=downloadSize, args=())
^------ This matches this ----------------^
downloadFile = threading.Thread(target=downloadFile, args=())
^------ Same here ------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use the same name for the global function and the local variable:

```
downloadSize = threading.Thread(target=downloadSize, args=())
```

That's not only confusing to human readers, it's also confusing to the Python compiler. Whenever you assign to a variable inside a function, that makes that variable name a local variable throughout that function.* So, when it goes to try to evaluate `threading.Thread(target=downloadSize, args=())`, because `downloadSize` is a local variable, which hasn't been assigned to yet, you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

The fix is simple: don't reuse variable names to mean different things in the same scope. Call it `downloadSizeThread`, or anything else.

(And of course you have the same problem on the next line.)

---

<sub>* Unless you use a `global` or `nonlocal` statement. But that would just cause a *different* problem—the first time you run this, it would replace the global function with the global thread object, and you'd never be able to access the function again.</sub>